# C++ string question

Tags: c++, string

I got a really simple question.

```
string str;
cin >> str;
cout << str;
```

if I type in "Hello World" the output I get is only "Hello". I know it probably has to do with whitespace. So my question is how I should write if I want the whitespace as well?

I have also tried to use **getline(cin, str);** but it will only read input first time and skip the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline(cin, str)` should work, but you may have to purge the input buffer before calling it if you encounter "char skipping":

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

Answer (score 1):

getline(cin, str) is the correct way. What do you mean it will only read input the first time and skip the rest?

Comment: if I write a cin first before getline(); e.g. cin >> var1; getline(cin, var2); it will get input for var1, but skip var2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `operator >>` leaves the next space/newline/whatever in the input buffer. So if you call `cin >> str` followed by `getline( cin, str )`, the getline operation will see the first character in the input buffer is a newline, and stop.